# PHP code inside echo (Heredoc in PHP or another way)

Tags: php

I have following code

```
<?php 
if(empty($db[$port])) echo '
<div class="html"> '.$db['name']. ' </div

<?php if ($num > 1) { ?> <div> <a href="index.php">(<?php echo $num-1; ?>) </a> </div> <?php } ?> '; ?>
```

I want to put this code inside echo ,and I can't get it to work.

I want to use Heredoc in PHP, but nothing happened, please show me an example.
or maybe another way to make it work, thanks

Comment: RTM on heredoc http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc and read it over carefully.

Comment: and if that's your *real* code, it's missing a `>` in `' </div` <<<

Comment: you can't recursively embed/execute php code. As written, your `if ($num` stuff is just part of the string, it's NOT executable code.

Answer (score 1):

**inside** echo statements you *do not* need `<?php` calls or the `?>` closing tags. Echo *is* a php statment.Use  full stops (.) and apostrophes (') to designate php data. See your third line of code. While it's not closed correctly, the `'.$db['name'].'` part is the correct way to concatenate php data within an echo statement.

Your first php echo statement is not closed correctly. Then there is a mish-mash of php and html for the second piece of code. It can be streamlined a great deal.

```
 <?php 
    if(empty($db[$port])) { 
      echo '<div class="html">'.$db['name'].'</div>';
    }
    if ($num > 1) { 
      echo '<div> <a href="index.php">'.($num - 1).'</a></div>'; 
   }
?>
```

This does assume the `$num` variable has been defined prior to the code you've shown.